# How to get gray scale image from intensity values in c++ or Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab

1.I have matrix 180*200 of intensity values.
2.I want image which represent this intensity values.

Comment: ... `imagesc(matrix)` ?

Comment: Hi Ram, I would recommend that you specify **one** language. The selected language should be chosen for how good it fits your needs. Anyway, I would also like to add that there are no graphics in c++ standard library. If you want to do graphics in c++ you will have to rely on third party libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have MATLAB on this machine (or any of your input) so I can't test.  But I think this is what you're looking for

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mat2gray.html

(Google is your friend)

The relevant code to you is:

```
I = mat2gray(A)
```

where `A` is the matrix containing your information

Comment: While I think a mathworks link is relatively stable, I have edited the question to include relevant parts directly